# Find the last two digits of $1717^{1717}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> $1717^{1717} \mod 100$

Since $\phi(100) = 40$ , we can transform this into:

> $17^{37}101^{37} \mod 100 = 17^{37} \mod 100$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: You can split the exponent, like $17^{37}=(17^2)^{18}\cdot 17$ for example.

Comment: You can look at a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315617/77775555-divided-by-191-find-the-remainder/2315677#2315677

Answer (score 4):

Since $17^3\equiv13\pmod{100}$, $17^{37}\pmod{100}$ is the inverse of $13$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*$, which turns out to be $77$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z/100\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/25\mathbf Z$$

$17\equiv 1\mod 4$, so $17^{37}\equiv \color{red}1\mod 4$. On the other hand, $\varphi(25)=20$, so $\;17^{37}\equiv 17^{-3}=(17^{-1})^3\mod 25$. As a Bézout's relation between $17$ and $25$ is $$3\cdot 17-2\cdot25=1,$$
we have $17^{-1}\equiv 3\mod 25$ and we finally get
$$17^{37}\equiv 3^3\equiv \color{red}2\mod 25.$$
Now use the inverse isomorphism: from the Bézout's relation between $4$ and $25$: $\;25-6\cdot4=1$, we deduce
$$17^{37}\equiv \color{red}1\cdot 25-\color{red}2\cdot6\cdot 4=-23\equiv 77\mod 100.$$

Answer (score 1):

$1717 \equiv 17$ (mod 100), since $1700 \equiv 0$ (mod 100).

Therefore, $1717^{1717} \equiv 17^{1717}$ (mod 100).

Now you have to compute the powers $17^n$ (mod 100). This gives what is sometimes called a **cycle**.

$17\equiv 17$ (mod 100)

$17^2\equiv 289 \equiv 89$ (mod 100)

$17^3 \equiv 4913 \equiv 13$, (mod 100)

$17^4 \equiv 83521 \equiv 21$ (mod 100)

and so on. You will finally obtain that $17^{21}\equiv 17$ (mod 100) again. Since $1717\equiv 17$ (mod 20), the last two digits of $1717^{1717}$ (mod 100) are the same as the last two digits of $17^{17}$ (mod 100) which are $77$.

Answer (score 1):

Like [What are the last two digits of $77^{17}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337375/what-are-the-last-two-digits-of-7717),

using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\lambda(100)=20\implies**17^{**17}\equiv17^{17}\pmod{100}$

Now $17^2=290-1, 17^{17}=17(290-1)^8$

Again, $\displaystyle(290-1)^8=(1-290)^8\equiv1-\binom81290\pmod{100}\equiv1-90\cdot8\equiv-19$

Now $-19\cdot17=-323\equiv77\pmod{100}$

**See also**:

[Find the last two digits of $ 7^{81} ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781)

[The last two digits of $13^{1010}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687434/the-last-two-digits-of-131010)

[Find the last two digits of $3^{45}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679842/find-the-last-two-digits-of-345)

[what are the last two digits of $2016^{2017}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031610/what-are-the-last-two-digits-of-20162017)

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$17^{37}\equiv(17^3)^{12}\cdot17\equiv(13^{3})^4\cdot17\equiv(-3)^4\cdot17\equiv1377\equiv77\pmod{100}.$$

or

$$17^{37}\equiv(17^4)^9\cdot17\equiv21^5\cdot21^4\cdot17\equiv1\cdot81\cdot17\equiv77\pmod{100}.$$