# Find the last two nonzero digits of $700^{2^{88}}$

Tags: number-theory

Find the last two nonzero digits of $700^{2^{88}}$. I tried approach this problem with modular arithmetic but haven't got much development. Any insights?

Comment: Note:  Since the factor of $100$ only contributes $0's$ to the result, it can be discarded.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362012/find-the-last-two-digits-of-781), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842588/find-the-last-two-digits-of-17171717?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yep. But what's next?

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts.  Once you discard the $0's$, it's a simple matter of computing the order of $7\pmod {100}$.

Comment: $700^{2^{88}} = 7^{2^88}*100^{2^{88}}$.  The $100^M$ just adds a bunch of zeros to the end.  So we can ignore them.  The last two non-zero digits will by the last two non zero digits of $7^{2^88}$. As $7$ and $10$ are relatively prime the last two digits will be non-zero.  So calculate $7^{2^{88}}\pmod {100}$.  ..... Oh, I suppose we may get that it is $0a$.  Does that count as the last two non-zero digits?  Well, we'll worry about that *if* it happens which it probably won't.

Comment: How much modular arithmetic do you know?  Do you know 1) Euler's Theorem and 2) did you understand what lulu means by "computing the order of $7\pmod{100}$?

Comment: @fleablood I think it does since $7^4 =2401$.

Comment: @rogerl  I believe you are addressing me, and you are quite right.  And I really *should* have realized that as $\phi(100) = 40$ and $2^{88}$ is very "four-y" that it'd be quite likely that would happen.....So what exactly *does* last two non-zero digits mean if the second to last digit is $0$.  I feel in good faith in must mean "the last two digits after we clear out all the leading zeros".  In which case this will be easy to see *is* $01$. As you pointed out.

Comment: @fleablood I agree; if it doesn't mean that then this is an unfairly worded question.

Comment: @lulu $\mod 100$ is not enough because the second to last digit is 0, see my answer.

Comment: @fleablood yes so i think we need mod 1000

Comment: So, use $\pmod {1000}$.  It's still easy.   Though I would read the question as asking for the first two digits after the long block of $0's$.

Comment: I can't think of any practical reason anyone would ask for the last two digits that are not $0$.  I can see if there's a long bloc $2*2^{88}$ zeros someone would want to know, well, whats after that, but I can see no reason anyone would care, after the one we have a zero so we go one digit further.... but... whatever....

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the last two nonzero  digits of $a=7^{2^{88}}$. Note that $7^4 \mod 100 =1$, so the next to the last digit of $a$ is $0$, so we need $a \pmod{1000}$.
Note that $7^{60}=1 \pmod{1000}$, so we need $2^{88}\mod 60$. Now $2^{88} =4^{14}\cdot 256= (4^3)^4\cdot 16\cdot 16 =16\cdot 16\cdot 16\equiv 16 \pmod{60}$. So $a=7^{16} \pmod{1000}=601$. So the last $2$ non-zero digits of $a$ are $6,1$.

Comment: I really really really doubt that's what they mean by the "last two non-zero digits".

Comment: @fleablood: Calm down.